# Synchromesh, Helical gear design

Tags: gears, automotive-design

What specifically, is the design principle behind the Helical shape of gears in a synchromesh transmission?

Are the Helical gear designed, in any known vehicle, to *disengage*? Is that why the gears are helical? To make the engage/disengage smoother?

As far as I know, the helicals on any synchomesh don't ever disengage.  Their linkage with the dog-clutch/blocking ring/mesh cone -- Basically the dog-clutch teeth is the only part that disengages.  Once the dog-teeth disengage, that will allow the entire helical to free-wheel on the mainshaft.  But the helical teeth NEVER come apart.

Answer (score 4):

Not only do helical gears run more smoothly and quieter than straight cut gears (as said in Nick C's answer), they also provide more surface area than do straight cut gears at the mesh point. This larger surface area means less chance of gear failure due to stress risers. In a straight cut gear, the load is transferred from tooth to tooth directly. In helical cut gears, the load is divided across different teeth which also makes it a stronger mesh. No single tooth is providing support for all of the load.

You can see what I'm talking about born out in this side by side comparison:

[image]

Even though the gears are the same width, the tooth length is longer for the helical cut gears. This provides more strength and better load distribution.

Comment: Since you brought in contact patch, you could maybe add that the contact patch (decided by the helix angle) is shared by a few teeth and is sliding(wrt a tooth). This in turns produce axial thrust of gear shafts and effects efficiency (Output shaft power / Input shaft power)* 100

Comment: While the effect on efficiency is probably negligible, the axial thrust is probably the only reason limiting their use in high torque applications. This is probably why spur gears are used for racing applications, not because they;re stronger. I might be wrong and missing other points

Comment: In citroëns I think mirrored helical gears (chevron shaped) were used, giving the benefit of helicals without giving the axial forces. At least that's what their logo is based on.

Comment: @Allman Did not know that (about the logo)

Answer (score 3):

It's generally because helical gears run more smoothly, and quieter, than straight-cut gears.

Quoting wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Gear#Helical):

> With parallel helical gears, each pair of teeth first make contact at a single point at one side of the gear wheel; a moving curve of contact then grows gradually across the tooth face to a maximum then recedes until the teeth break contact at a single point on the opposite side. In skew gears, teeth suddenly meet at a line contact across their entire width causing stress and noise.

You'll notice this if you ever hear a car with a straight-cut 'box (such as many racing Minis) - they make a very distinctive whine...

Comment: Yeah, that's good.  Can you say with a large degree certainty that that is the MAIN reason?  Is it known that helicals disengage?

Comment: I've never seen any automotive application that involves gears of either type disengaging from each other, AFAIK all gearboxes use dog clutches to engage gear to shaft - but there might be some obscure one I've not come across!

Comment: Right, so with large equipment where synchomesh is not appropriate, you have to double-de-clutch, and engage/disengage is accomplished with the dog-clutch.  But you never see *non-dog* gear teeth (straight or helical) actually unmeshing.

Comment: @AndyzSmith - your next question could be , why use spur gears in racing applications?

Comment: @AndyzSmith correct. I suspect that the other reason for gears actually unmeshing is that it would require either moving the shafts away from each other - which would be complicated, or sliding the gears themselves along the shafts, and crashing them into one another - ok-ish when stationary, but at several thousand RPM, that would soon destroy them!

Comment: But when you have a legit dog-clutch, that's the only way it can work right, a certain amount of crashing and crunching.   That's why in a race or dump truck transmission, the recommendation is to shift hard quickly.  The dogs will crash, but if you shafts are close in speed, and you get the full breadth of the lower part the dog engaged quickly.   no damage, or just long term wear.

Comment: Wait, so, to your knowledge, all kind of auto trans use the freewheel bearing on shaft technique?  You would have to go to like a bicycle deraueller to get something where the shaft or gear actually TRANSLATES? Right?

Comment: The reverse gear on otherwise-helical manual transmissions is generally straight-cut, is it not? That may be a more familiar source of the typical whine.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, since it uses an idler gear, the spur gears allow the gears to slide into contact.

Comment: @AndyzSmith I don't know about Automatics (or motorbikes for that matter), I've only ever looked at manual boxes...

Comment: @chilljeet So in a spur, you don't always have a dog clutch allowing the spur itself to freewheel on the shaft? You can have a direct slide-into engage of the spur teeth?  It seems like you would want a dog, then,

Comment: @AndyzSmith that is only the case for reverse. Read paulsters answer!

Comment: @chilljeet So in a racing, spur application, the changing of the gear ratio, the engaged gear, is still by locking and unlocking the dog, which is locked to the shaft, to the spur.  So the advantage of a spur, generally is probably due not wanting to shim and bear axial loads within a given case design.

Comment: @AndyzSmith yes. This is called a Constant Mesh Gearbox

Comment: @chilljeet Yeah.  Got it.  Reverse is different even in a constant mesh because you want to invert the rotation.  And WAY back in the day, there was such a thing as sliding mesh, but no more. Totally obsolete.

Comment: @chilljeet Reverse is also different because you can be sure the output shaft is at 0 RPM.

Comment: @AndyzSmith Else you hear the "grinding noise" as it fails to mesh. If you keep your car in neutral (not clutched) , bring the rev up, and immediately try to engage neutral, you'l hear the grinding, as the shaft , like you said, isn't at 0 RPM

Comment: Ok, I got it.  Somebody summarize and i'll put that as the answer.  So, briefly, helicals are used today because constant mesh design makes their use possible, and they are chosen because they are quieter and carry more load.  Spur gears are used with a constant mesh design, in certain cases, probably to alleviate axial loading related to helicals.  Spur gears can be used in a sliding mesh configuration, but not helicals.  The use of sliding mesh in general is basically obsolete.  Spur gears in sliding mesh are used today only as Reverse.